# Springboot test failed to load ApplicationContext in Junit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I'm trying to create unit/integration test using Junit5 for specific service classes to avoid overload the whole project.

So here I try to run the `EmailService` with its dependency classes inside, but I got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext. Error creating bean with name 'emailSenderService. No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.'`.

Do I must have to run the whole application to test a single service?

build.yml

```
{
    testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.1"
}
```

Service:

```
public class EmailSenderService {
    private final JavaMailSender sender;
    private final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
    private final MessageSource i18n;
    public EmailSenderService(JavaMailSender sender, SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine,
                              @Qualifier("messageSource") MessageSource i18n) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
        this.i18n = i18n;
    }
}
```

test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = {EmailSenderService.class}
)
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
class EmailServiceTest {

    private static GreenMail smtp;

    @Autowired
    private EmailSenderService mailService;

    @BeforeAll
    static void init() {
        smtp = new GreenMail(new ServerSetup(3026,null,"smtp"));
        smtp.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDown() {
        smtp.stop();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void clearUp() throws FolderException {
        smtp.purgeEmailFromAllMailboxes();
    }

    @Test
    void testNewBidRequestEmail() throws MessagingException {
        EmailMessageTemplateDto contact = new EmailMessageTemplateDto("test","test@test.com","test message");
        mailService.sendUserContactEmail(contact);
        Assertions.assertTrue(smtp.waitForIncomingEmail(1));
    }
}
```

Error:

> 2019-04-03 14:56:06.146  WARN 732 --- [           main]
>   o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'emailSenderService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {} 2019-04-03 14:56:06.153 ERROR 732 --- [
>   main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   com.server.server.service.EmailSenderService required a bean of
>   type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not
>   be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' in your
>   configuration.
>
> 2019-04-03 14:56:06.159 ERROR 732 --- [           main]
>   o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
>   allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@342c38f8]
>   to prepare test instance
>   [com.server.server.test.junit.EmailServiceTest@4c7a078]
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you really don't have a `JavaMailSender` available (and you wouldn't want a real one during your tests). You have four options:

- Register a mock/stub `JavaMailSender` bean in a test configuration.
- Use auto-configuration to make your `EmailSenderService` itself `@ConditionalOnBean(JavaMailSender.class)` and register a stub if there isn't one (this is usually what I do for testing "does the system send transactional mail?").
- In this case, since you're actually trying to test the `EmailSenderService` itself, set `spring.mail.host: localhost` in your `application-test` properties (or an annotation).
- Don't use Spring DI at all here. The major advantage of constructor injection is that you can hand-instantiate your beans, and you could `new` up your `EmailSenderService` and its dependencies.

If I understand the intended scope of your test, #3 is probably the solution to go with for you.

Comment: 1st option: If I use a mock `JavaMailSender`, will it be able to send email? For 2nd option, I'll try to learn more about the `@ConditionalOnBean` annotation before I ask some question. About the 3rd option, I already have a default `application.yml` file with `spring.mail.host: localhost` before I submitted this question. 4th option, do I need to retrieve any parameter of the main spring application to create `new EmailSenderService`?

Comment: @LunaticJape It won't send real mail if you do that, which is why it's probably not the best option for what you're wanting to test here. In the third option, you should be getting a `JavaMailSender`; make sure you have `spring-boot-starter-mail` included, and if it still isn't working, use `--debug` to get the auto-configuration report and post it. For the option 4, it depends on what you want to test; you don't need Spring at all, but it can be useful to test that your messages and template engine are configured correctly in your Spring context.